# IDENT_CURRENT returning less value than MAX(ID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestQueue]
(
    [QueueID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate] [DATETIME] NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_SecurityQueue_EntryDate]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [AsOfDate] [DATE] NULL,
    [ItemID] [VARCHAR](32) NULL,
    [ItemType] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Message] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_QueueID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QueueID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a SQL job that runs daily, inserting data into this table, the insert statement is like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.RequestQueue( AsOfDate , ItemID , ItemType )
VALUES  ( GETDATE(),'ABC1','TYPE1' )
```

This daily job was running fine for over a year, until it broke last night with below message:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 25
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_QueueID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RequestQueue'. The duplicate key value is (1698922).

I checked identity value as below:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.RequestQueue')
```

returns 1698922

```
SELECT MAX([QueueID]) 
FROM [dbo].[RequestQueue]
```

returns 1699269

What messed up the `IDENT_CURRENT`?

The SQL job is on daily schedule, running once a day.

There are some concurrent readers for the RequestQueue table, they also issue update statements, but of course, never on PK column.

There are no other insert jobs/processes anywhere else.

Comment: Could it be that you have users inserting records manually?

Comment: There are no manual inserts, and no other automated process either. This table is on a business sensitive database, there are layers of control to prevent manual data manipulation.

Comment: are there any insert triggers on the table?

Comment: It seems your identity was stucked because of isolation level - in what isolation level is code running - read uncommitted?

Comment: Read committed.

Comment: If somebody has similar issue and just needs a way to fix it, I fixed it by issueing command: DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.RequestQueue', RESEED, 1699269);   I have the number 1699269 here because that is the current MAX(ID) in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table is reseed-ed some times using either like below commands

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTable, RESEED, 999)
```

Comment: Thanks Kannan. It does look like reseeded, but I have every reason to believe that there is no manual execution of such commands, or for any data manipulation command for that matter. Could it be caused by concurrent processes that update the message column in the table?